# How can i pass a vuex computed property to vuejs chart data?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

Im having a problem creating a chart, the problem is that the chart data come from vuex store to the vue component then using computed i have a function that do some changes to the data then i try pass this new data to the chart data using a method.

I tried calling the method that pass the data from computed to chart data from mounted(), created(), beforemount(), beforecreate(), and nothing works

THIS IS CHART CONTAINER VUE:

```
<template>
  <!-- Main content -->
  <section class="content">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">

             <!-- AREA CHART -->
                 <div class="grid">
                     <ChartPie/>
                 </div>
             <!-- AREA CHART -->

             <!-- AREA CHART -->
                 <div class="grid">

                 </div>

           </div>
           <!-- /.col (LEFT) -->

           <div class="col-md-6">
             <!-- AREA CHART -->
                 <div class="grid">

                 </div>
             <!-- AREA CHART -->

             <!-- AREA CHART -->
                 <div class="grid">

                 </div>

           </div>
           <!-- /.col (RIGHT) -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.row -->

       </section>
       <!-- /.content -->
     </template>





   <script>
      import ChartPie from "../components/chart-pie";
      export default {
        components: {
          ChartPie,
        }
      };
      </script>
```

THIS IS VUEX STORE:
Actions:

```
actions:{
loadMachines ({commit}){
            axios.get("api/machine")
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.data)
                let machines= data.data.data
                commit('SET_MACHINES',machines)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        },
        loadPrevents ({commit}){
            axios.get("api/prevent")
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.data)
                let prevents= data.data.data
                commit('SET_PREVENTS',prevents)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        },
}
```

Mutations:

```
SET_MACHINES (state, machines){
            state.machines=machines
        },
        SET_PREVENTS (state, prevents){
            state.prevents=prevents
        }
```

State:

```
state:{
        intervenants: [],
        fabriquants: [],
        machines: [],
        prevents: []
    },
```

***THIS IS CHART VUE: (MOST IMPORTANT ONE)***

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 class="bg-info text-center" >Nombre de panne par unité</h2>

    <div class="card">
      <chartjs-pie
        :bind="true"
        :datasets="datasets"
        :labels="labels"
        :option="option"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import {mapState} from 'vuex'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [],
          backgroundColor: ["#b388ff", "#82b1ff", "#80d8ff", "#80d8ff", "#80d8ff", "#80d8ff", "#80d8ff"],
          hoverBackgroundColor: ["#673ab7", "#2196f3", "#03a9f4", "#03a9f4", "#03a9f4", "#03a9f4", "#03a9f4"]
        }
      ],
      labels: ["Meubles modulaires", "Les mètiers", "Meubles massifs", "Panoverre", "Métal design", "Poly-meuble", "L'art de salon"],
      option: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadPrevents');
    this.$store.dispatch('loadMachines');
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
        'prevents',
        'machines',
    ]),
      panne() {
      let machines_en_panne= []
      for (var i = 0, len = this.$store.state.prevents.length; i < len; i++) {
          machines_en_panne[i]= this.$store.state.prevents[i].machine ;
      }
      let countp= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
      for (var i = 0, len = this.$store.state.machines.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ( machines_en_panne.includes(this.$store.state.machines[i].nom) ){
          if (this.$store.state.machines[i].unite == 'Meubles modulaires')
          countp[0] ++;
          if (this.$store.state.machines[i].unite == 'Les mètiers')
          countp[1] ++;
          if (this.$store.state.machines[i].unite == 'Meubles massifs')
          countp[2] ++;
          if (this.$store.state.machines[i].unite == 'Panoverre')
          countp[3] ++;
          if (this.$store.state.machines[i].unite == 'Métal design')
          countp[4] ++;
          if (this.$store.state.machines[i].unite == 'Poly-meuble')
          countp[5] ++;
          if (this.$store.state.machines[i].unite == 'L\'art de salon')
          countp[6] ++;
        }
      }
      return countp;
    },
  },
  created(){
    this.datasets[0].data=this.panne
    this.loaded=true
  }
}
</script>
```

you can see in DevTools that the computed property got the correct values but the method that pass this value to data is doing that before the two mapstate complete loading data i think so always i get the initial values [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF4ba.jpg)

[Computed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgY2p.jpg)

[VueX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0nFL.jpg)

***EDIT: SUPER WEIRD***

i put the line of codes that pass the value from computed to data() in computed itself and know when i click in the vue component in devtools it works and rerender the chart with the correct values . 
What should i do ????

Comment: Try doing your API calls in created() hook instead of mounted()

Comment: I did not work, the data still grab the value from computed prperty before dispatch

Comment: Good to see you’ve got it working. Personally I would do all the logic in your computed property server-side.

Comment: Actually it is not working, i need to go to devTools and click on the vue component to make it work !

Comment: Why not do the population of data in your `store` and assign the computed property directly as the source for your chart?

Comment: How to do that ?